# What is this symbol used for?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have seen the symbol $\subsetneqq$ in a Probability exercise. What is it used for? In the exercise it seemed to mean "proper subset of", but then in what is it different from $\subsetneq$?

Comment: It's equivalent, just another choice of notation.

Comment: It has the same meaning as $\subsetneq$, but the strike-through in $\subsetneqq$ is more difficult to overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. The author simply chose to use different notation.